# C++ - how to create a multimap with 4 variables and 4 keys

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, logic

I want to create a class like below

```
class enumClass
{
    int msdnEnum;
    std::string msdnEnumString; 
    int localEnum;
    std::string localEnumString;
}

std::set<enumClass_Objects> enums; // all msdnEnums are unique, same aplies to other three.

enums.find(given_msdnEnum)->FourthVariable;
enums.find(given_localEnum)->FirstVariable;
enums.find(given_msdnEnumStr)->anyVariable;
enums.find(given_localEnumStr)->anyVariable;
```

I referred boost::multiIndex.  But I don't think that it helps on this case. Can anybody say the way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
 I am not that much good in reading template classes. As for as I am concerning I didn't find any "find" methods in multiIndex.  I saw only sorting out things in that example(the first  basic example:[link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/example/basic.cpp)). Suggestions&advices are always welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example using boost.multi_index:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

struct enumClass
{
  int msdnEnum;
  std::string msdnEnumString; 
  int localEnum;
  std::string localEnumString;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
  enumClass,
  bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<enumClass, int, &enumClass::msdnEnum> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<enumClass, std::string, &enumClass::msdnEnumString> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<enumClass, int, &enumClass::localEnum> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<enumClass, std::string, &enumClass::localEnumString> >
  >
> enumClassSet;

int main()
{
  enumClassSet enums;
  enums.get<0>().find(/*given_msdnEnum*/);     // index 0 is enumClass::msdnEnum
  enums.get<1>().find(/*given_msdnEnumStr*/);  // index 1 is enumClass::msdnEnumString
  enums.get<2>().find(/*given_localEnum*/);    // index 2 is enumClass::localEnum
  enums.get<3>().find(/*given_localEnumStr*/); // index 3 is enumClass::localEnumString
}
```

Tag classes could be used to access the indices by name rather than ordinal index as well, usage of which would look like this:

```
struct byMsdnEnum;
struct byMsdnEnumStr;
struct byLocalEnum;
struct byLocalEnumStr;

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
  enumClass,
  bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<byMsdnEnum>, bmi::member<enumClass, int, &enumClass::msdnEnum> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<byMsdnEnumStr>, bmi::member<enumClass, std::string, &enumClass::msdnEnumString> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<byLocalEnum>, bmi::member<enumClass, int, &enumClass::localEnum> >,
    bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<byLocalEnumStr>, bmi::member<enumClass, std::string, &enumClass::localEnumString> >
  >
> enumClassSet;

int main()
{
  enumClassSet enums;
  enums.get<byMsdnEnum>().find(/*given_msdnEnum*/);
  enums.get<byMsdnEnumStr>().find(/*given_msdnEnumStr*/);
  enums.get<byLocalEnum>().find(/*given_localEnum*/);
  enums.get<byLocalEnumStr>().find(/*given_localEnumString*/);
}
```

The difference between the two approaches is purely aesthetic, and of course the tag classes could be named whatever you want rather than `byMsdnEnum`, etc. Also note that hashed indices could be used rather than ordered indices, which would give your indices the behavior of `std::unordered_map` rather than `std::map`.

Comment: @ildjarn I tried to put typedef boost::multi_index boost_Multi; But it didn't work. Can I know why?

Comment: `boost::multi_index` is a namespace, not a type, and consequently cannot be typedef'd. If you want to create a namespace alias, do `namespace boost_Multi = boost::multi_index;` as I've done with `bmi` in my code example.

Comment: @ildjarn How to add structs with this enumClassSet

Comment: In the code I've shown (using `ordered_unique` indices exclusively), `enumClassSet` has the exact same `insert` overloads as `std::map` would have. I trust that you can find a `std::map` reference... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn but std:map accepts pair via ::insert(), here I got error when I used bmi::insert_() that it is a private member

Comment: One `std::map<K, V>::insert` overload accepts a `std::map<K, V>::value_type` argument, which happens to always be `std::pair<K const, V>`, yes; the conceptual `value_type` of `enumClassSet` is `enumClass`, so `enumClassSet` has an `insert` (**not** `insert_`) overload taking a single `enumClass` just as you would expect.

Comment: @ildjarn Can you please say How to access the index by tagname, as you showed in the above "main" code.

Answer (score 4):

boost multiindex is exactly what you need in this case. Construct four indexes for the four keys - I guess given you guarantee that they will all be unique, make them unique indexes (I believe only one of them can be hashed_unique, but I think you can make the other three ordered_unique), and then do your searches on the each index depending on what you are searching by.

Comment: prabhakaran: "I referred boost::multiIndex. But I don't think that it helps on this case." - why don't you list the specific problems you encountered.  Similarly, with PeterK's answer "that will create problems" is not very useful.  Remember that you don't know how to do something, so somewhere you see problems there will hopefully be a solution offered.  If you casually dismiss answers without explanation you can't expect anyone's answer - right or wrong - to lead anywhere.

Comment: @prabhakaran, the container itself does not have any find methods AFAIK, however the normal mode of operation is that you get a particular index of the container, and there is a find method in the index to search for your key - look at the example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#list_ops

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot use 2 maps? ( std::map< int, std::string> ). If you need to find both of the string variables by any of those two keys, then you could solve it by having a map that would pair for example `msdnEnum` with both strings and then have a map that would pair `localEnum` with `msdnEnum`. Than any lookup via `msdnEnum` would be done directly and a lookup via `localEnum` would first do a translation to `msdnEnum` and then do a direct lookup.

Comment: that will create problems in implementation. And also see the edit.

Comment: I want to make it as a single line code. From the edit you can see that my requirements is more than the std::map